# NGINX send path as variable to PHP except if path is a file path

Tags: php, regex, nginx

I want to pass all my path to index.php?page=path. For example:

```
domain.com/a/b/c -> index.php?page=a/b/c
```

Therefore this is my NGINX conf file:

```
location ~ /(?P<arg1>.*)$ {
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       /index.php?page=$arg1;
}
```

As far as I know, query string should be everything after .com, right? I'm passing arg1 to it. However, I wanted to ignore truly file paths like `/file.jpg` or `/images/favicon.ico`. I could simply negate them in regex but then they'd have no path at all.

So how to match `/anything` to `index.php?page=anything` except for files and actually deliver those files?

Comment: The query string is everything after the `?`, but why are you changing the `QUERY_STRING`? These variables should be imported using `include fastcgi_params;`. Do you have a `location /` block? That is where you need to make changes to process existent files and send everything else to the controller script.

Comment: @RichardSmith I'm lost. The only thing I need is to map any path which is not a file to index.php?page=path, so that's why I didn't make a / location. I guess I don't need QUERY_STRING then?

Comment: Do you have a working configuration that renders files and PHP scripts correctly? That should be the starting point before you add these additional requirements on top.

Comment: Yes, I have a .htaccess file from apache. I'm trying to move to nginx https://pastebin.com/VuBYd3Mw

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs, any feedback on existing answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use below

```
location ~ /(.*)$ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page=$1;
}
```

This will first check if file or directory exists if not then pass it to the `index.php` file

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Apache's .htaccess, the equivalent setting under Nginx would be:

```
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then index.php?page=$args.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page=$args;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know nginx, but assuming truly/real path is something that ends with some kind of extension, and that you can write several rules with top rules having higher priority, you could write 2 rules like these:

First rule matches an url that ends with an extension: ( dot + word ) and does nothing:

```
/^.*[.]\w+$/
```

second rule matches anything and captures:

```
/(.*)/
```

If that is not possible, you could try to use a rule that matches urls like these: foo/bar/foo/bar/...

```
(\w+(?:\/\w+)*\/?)
```

If you don't want to allow last / bar, just use

```
(\w+(?:\/\w+)*)
```

Answer (score 0):

The use case you mention is very common, and it's detailed in [the common Nginx pitfalls page](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) under the section *Front Controller Pattern Web Apps*

As per the aforementioned page,  for Drupal, Joomla, etc., just use this inside your location block:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

Since you want to use the "page" variable name, your code will look as follows:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page=$uri&args;
}
```

The part `$uri/` is relevant only if you want to serve content from directories, for example if you want to serve a Wordpress blog from `yourdomain.com/blog/`. If that's not the case, you can remove the `$uri/` part.

My advice is to not use `page` as the variable to pass the section/route to PHP, because you might end up having a confusion between *which section of the website to show* vs. *which page number*. *Page* is misleading, I'd use *route* instead.

Of course, your mileage may vary and you may require something more complex based on your needs, but for basic sites, these will work perfectly. You should always start simple and build from there.

Additionally, to make debugging easier, consider using a verbose [error log setting](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log), I'd use `info` or `notice` to debug routing:

```
error_log logs/error.log info;
```

Good luck and keep us posted on how you solved the issue.