# subdirectories blog post wordpress not shown in laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I'am using wordpress as my blog in my laravel site. The wordpress blog are placed in subdirectories so that the domain of the wordpress is mydomain.com/blog.

I've tested it in my localhost and it works perfectly. But when i deployed it on server the site can show the homepage of my blog. But it **can't display the blog's page ex. domain.com/blog/contact** (404 Page not found) .

I've done several steps like [changed the .htaccess](http://www.cesarserna.com/htaccess-rewrite-rules-laravel-lumen-wordpress/) and define the WP_HOME /WP_SITEURL but it still doesn't works to show my blog post .

Here is **my wordpress .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And here are **my  laravel site's .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ # <=== NEW LINE!!!!
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: can you show both your Laravel `.htaccess`, and Wordpress `.htaccess` file?

Comment: i've added the files in my question, do you see something wrong there?

Comment: Seems every thing ok with all your `.htaccess` files. How about your wordpress directory? It's inside `laravel_project/public/blog` right?

Comment: yes, that's why it works well in my localhost. but it goes wrong in displaying the post when i deployed it in server

Comment: On your server it using `nginx` or `apache`? Because `.htaccess` files configuration will only works under `apache`

Comment: i just realized that it affect on all my blog's page not just the blog post. ah i see, i'm using nginx. thanks for reminding me

Comment: If you are using nginx, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50404862/4902099